# How to convert a recursion with multiple recursive calls into an iteration? I already know how to do it when there is only one recursive call

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion, iteration

Here is how I would convert a recursive function that only has one recursive call (I'll use JavaScript)

```
function f(n){
    if(n>0){
        f(n-1);
        doStuff(n); //this could be anything
    }
}
```

Iterative form

```
function f(n){
    let stack = [];
    while(n>0){
        stack.push(n);
        n = n-1;
    }
    while(stack.length!=0){
        doStuff(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to go about a function like this

```
function f(n){
    if(n>0){
        f(n-1);
        f(n-2); //how to deal with this?
        doStuff(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a bit more information on the stack, like *what* to do with the value on the stack: perform `f`, or perform `doStuff`.

So then it can become like this:

```js
function f(n) {
    const stack = [[0, n]];
    while (stack.length) {
        const [state, n] = stack.pop();
        if (state) {
            doStuff(n);
        } else if (n > 0) {
            // Three tasks to perform -- stack in reverse order
            stack.push([1, n], [0, n-2], [0, n-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach also works for your first example, where you only have one recursive call. The only statement that needs to change (in the above code) is the `push` call:

```js
            stack.push([1, n], [0, n-1]);
```